# Tensorflow and PyTorch hang on initializing with CUDA

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, archlinux

When I try to run a very minimal Tensorflow example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

c = tf.constant([1,2,3])
```

The system hangs forever (at least for ten minutes) with no sign of what it is doing. It uses 100% of one virtual CPU core when in this state. When run in a Juypter notebook the kernel outputs this to the console:

```
2020-03-31 11:12:04.840507: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-03-31 11:12:04.840576: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-03-31 11:12:04.840589: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
2020-03-31 11:12:05.521172: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-03-31 11:12:05.539193: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-31 11:12:05.539639: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1070 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.7845GHz coreCount: 15 deviceMemorySize: 7.93GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
2020-03-31 11:12:05.539841: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-03-31 11:12:05.541113: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-03-31 11:12:05.542119: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-03-31 11:12:05.542324: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-03-31 11:12:05.543632: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-03-31 11:12:05.544401: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-03-31 11:12:05.547212: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-03-31 11:12:05.547337: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-31 11:12:05.548015: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-31 11:12:05.548512: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-03-31 11:12:05.567845: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3393550000 Hz
2020-03-31 11:12:05.568364: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x564107e16440 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-03-31 11:12:05.568395: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

I did have Tensorflow working previously on this system, so I think this might be some sort of library issue that got caused by a system update.

The GPU is an Nvidia GTX 1070. Tensorflow version is 2.1.0, and hasn't changed since when it was working. Running Arch Linux, if that matters.

I tried downgrading from CUDA 10.2 to 10.1, but the issue still occurs.

I can also reproduce this with PyTorch:

```
import torch
import transformers

t = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
t.cuda()
```

(`import transformers` prevents a "CUDA: Out of memory" issue - there must be something it does that initializes PyTorch that I don't know how to do.)

This has the same issue, where it freezes pegging one CPU core, though it produces less output:

```
020-03-31 11:13:41.428483: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-03-31 11:13:41.428571: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-03-31 11:13:41.428587: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
```

I'm pretty sure the complaints about TensorRT are not relevant, because when I had this working previously it would output those as well.

How can I resolve this issue? Or at least, what else can I do to determine what it is doing while frozen?

Answer (score 1):

My issue was caused by a ulimit I had set on the amount of virtual memory the Python process was aloud to consume (with `ulimit -Sv 12000000` in zsh). I don't know why that would cause it to hang, but if anyone else encounters a similar issue, make sure you aren't limiting virtual memory.